# String array name search

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So I have a file which has all presidents in it - their first name, middle initial (if any), and last name.

The file needs to be read in, and a user can enter a president's name to search for it, and that president should be displayed.

I have it displaying the president if a user searches by first name or by last name, but not by both.

For example, the external file contains:

```
George,Washington,(1789-1797)
Franklin,D.,Roosevelt,(1933-1945)
... and so on with all the presidents
```

I need the user to be able to either type in the first name, the last name, or both first and last name and get the desired result (the date is irrelevant for the most part).

Tried lots of different things, but not getting there as far as displaying the president if user searches by first and last name.

Here is what I got so far:

```
public class NameSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            // read from presidents file
            Scanner presidentsFile = new Scanner(new File("Presidents.txt"));
            // scanner for user input
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            // create array list of each line in presidents file
            ArrayList<String> presidentsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

            // prompt user to enter a string to see if it matches with a president's name
            System.out.println("Enter a search string of letters to find a president match: ");
            // store user input
            String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

            // add president file info to array list linesInPresidentFile
            while (presidentsFile.hasNextLine()) {
                presidentsArrayList.add(presidentsFile.nextLine());
            } // end while loop

            String presidentNamesArray[] = presidentsArrayList.toArray(new String[presidentsArrayList.size()]);
            String results = searchArray(presidentNamesArray, userInput);

            //System.out.println("\nThe presidents who have \"" + userInput + "\" as part of their name are: ");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // print out error (if any) to screen
            System.out.println(ex.toString());

        } // end catch block

    } // end main

    // method to search for a specific value in an array
    public static String searchArray(String array[], String value) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
                String splitter[] = array[i].split(" ,");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitter));
            }

        }
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }

}
```

Comment: Umm... what? Yea I want to ask lol...

Answer (score 2):

There is another way in which I might have implemented this.Read the file inputs and stored them as objects (class with lname, fname and year perhaps). In this way you can search for lname from user input, match it up with its corresponding fname (as same objects).  The creation can be done once and searching can be done in a while loop implementing users consent of continuing the search.

```
//define your class like this:
static int i; //to keep a track of number of objects
public class dummy{
string fname;
string lname;
string year;
};

while the file content exists:
read the line
dummy dobj[i++] = new dummy();//allocate memory for the object 
split the different parameters (fname, lname, year) from the read line
put these read parameters into the object 
dobj[i].fname = first;
dobj[i].lname = second;
dobj[i].year = y;

//ask your user to enter the query in a specified format
//if he enters lname, compare your input to all the object's lname, and so on
//in case of lname && fname, compare your input to the lname first and then check for the corresponding objects fname, if they match.. display
```

Actually, there are many ways in which you can achieve what you wish to program. You can ask use the array list indices to solve it. If you take in the input from the user in a particular format, you can map it to the index in that list. Further, if you want to use first name and last name together, you may use these index representing the first and last name to come from same list.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow unfortunately. Think you can post some start-up code please?

Comment: I am not a not proficient in java, but ya, i can help u out with a pseudo code

Comment: Not proficient in java myself, and can't really follow that in terms of code, but thanks alot for helpin out!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you may have problems searching by both first and last names is because you have to match your input exactly (ignoring case of course).  What I mean is if you use `George Washington` as input, your program will not find a match for the `George,Washington,(1789-1797)` line. This is because your program treats `George Washington` as one string. Note: the input is missing the comma, so it will not be considered a substring of `George,Washington,(1789-1797)`. If you used `George,Washington` as your input string, then your program would print the George Washington line. Your program just searches if the input string is a substring of any of the lines in your file.  It does not search for a first name or last name specifically. If you used `in` as your input string, then you would get a match for both George Wash**in**gton and Frankl**in** D. Roosevelt.
What you could do is take your input data and split it and search for each of the terms. You can either accept lines that match all of the terms provided, or at least one of the terms provided.

```
public static String searchArray(String array[], String value) {
    // Uses both blank spaces and commas as delimiters
    String[] terms = value.toLowerCase().Split("[ ,]"); 

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String line = array[i].toLowerCase();
        boolean printIfAllMatch = true;
        boolean printIfAtLeastOneMatches = false;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < terms.length; j++) {
            // Check that all terms are contained in the line
            printIfAllMatch &= line.Contains(terms[j]); 
            // Check that at least one term is in the line
            printIfAtLeastOneMatches |= line.Contains(terms[j]); 
        }

        String splitter[] = array[i].split(" ,");
        if (printIfAllMatch) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitter));
        }
        if(printIfAtLeastOneMatches) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitter));
        }

    }
    //I'm not sure why you're returning the original array as a string
    //I would think it would make more sense to return an Array of filtered data.
    return Arrays.toString(array);
}
```

This does not take name ordering into account.  If that's what you're going for, then I would suggest making a class and parsing each line in the file as an new object and trying to match the first term provided with the first name and second term provided with the last name, or something to that effect.

Comment: I appreciate all that. However, this displays nothing regardless of what I type...

Comment: Could you please provide examples of what is and is not working? I guess I don't quite understand your problem.